# Не могу присоединить Button к ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, button

Activity_main:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

list_item:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is Title"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time_display_box"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/_00_30"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:right="@+id/time_display_box"
        android:text="@string/start" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Main_activity:

```
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> mHeroesList;
private static final String TITLE = "heroesname"; 
private static final String TIMER = "timer"; 
private static final String ICON = "icon";  
private static final String BUTTON = "button";  

private static final int MILLIS_PER_SECOND = 1000;
private static final int SECONDS_TO_COUNTDOWN = 30;
private TextView countdownDisplay;
private CountDownTimer timer;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    countdownDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_display_box);
    Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startbutton);
    /*startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                showTimer(SECONDS_TO_COUNTDOWN * MILLIS_PER_SECOND);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            }
        }
    });*/

    // создаем массив списков
    mHeroesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    HashMap<String, Object> hm;

    hm = new HashMap<>();
    hm.put(TITLE, "Naga Siren");
    hm.put(TIMER, R.id.time_display_box);
    hm.put(ICON, R.drawable.naga_siren);
    mHeroesList.add(hm);

    hm = new HashMap<>();
    hm.put(TITLE, "Enigma");
    hm.put(TIMER, R.id.time_display_box);
    hm.put(ICON, R.drawable.enigma);
    mHeroesList.add(hm);

    hm = new HashMap<>();
    hm.put(TITLE, "Chen");
    hm.put(TIMER, R.id.time_display_box);
    hm.put(ICON, R.drawable.chen);
    mHeroesList.add(hm);

    hm = new HashMap<>();
    hm.put(TITLE, "Zeus");
    hm.put(TIMER, R.id.time_display_box);
    hm.put(ICON, R.drawable.zeus);
    mHeroesList.add(hm);

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mHeroesList,
            R.layout.list_item, new String[]{TITLE, TIMER, ICON, BUTTON},
            new int[]{R.id.text1, R.id.time_display_box, R.id.img, R.id.startbutton});

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
}

private void showTimer(int countdownMillis) {
    if(timer != null) { timer.cancel(); }
    timer = new CountDownTimer(countdownMillis, MILLIS_PER_SECOND) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            countdownDisplay.setText("counting down: " +
                    millisUntilFinished / MILLIS_PER_SECOND);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            countdownDisplay.setText("Cooldown is refreshed");
        }
    }.start();
}

AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        HashMap<String, Object> itemHashMap = (HashMap <String, Object>) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        String titleItem = itemHashMap.get(TITLE).toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "You chose " + titleItem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

Как вставить в `ListView` кнопку для активации таймера?

Почему значение у таймера 213, а я указывал 30?

Comment: В общем ВСЕ неправильно. Во первых, вы не можете получать ссылки на виджеты из айтемов списка обращаясь к разметке, которая содержит сам список.  Во вторых, что значит "вставить кнопку" - она у вас уже "вставлена" в разметке. В третьих,при такой разметке, значение у таймера содержится в строковом ресурсе `@string/_00_30` , а `countdownDisplay` указывает на что угодно, только не на `TextView` с таймером  в айтеме. Странно, что оно вообще компилируется.

Answer (score 1):

Вся беда у вас в том, что вы используете стандартный адаптер для ListView. Пишите свой.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
...
Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startbutton);
```

Тут вы пытаетесь найти Button по id = startbutton в разметке activity_main.xml
Написав свой адаптер, вы будете обращаться непосредственно к элементу списка - ViewGroup, состоящему из вьюшек (представлений) из разметки list_item.xml, вот там и надо искать Button по id и манипулировать им как нужно, но никак не в OnCreate()